# Is there a dotted box placeholder symbol?

Tags: symbols

I am looking for a dotted box as a placeholder for a "normal sized" character.

For example I would like to put it under a function to represent the placeholder, e.g. `\sqrt{\dottedbox}`. Something like this:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with "normal sized"? A capital letter? A letter like "g"?

Comment: @TeXnician Good question. I am not sure. A capital letter sounds good to me.

Comment: @TeXnician I have added a small image. Maybe that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`stix` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/stix) provides a `\dottedsquare` symbol that could fit.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix}
\begin{document}                         
     $\dottedsquare\sqrt{\dottedsquare}$
\end{document}
```

[image: Rendering]

Answer (score 12):

Not a dotted box, but a dashed box with  adapted parameters. Here is a code with `dashbox`: I defined a  `\dashedph` command with an optional argument (default: capital H). I also suggest a simple `\colorph` (colorbox place holder):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}%
\usepackage{dashbox}%
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}

\newcommand\dashedph[1][H]{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\setlength{\dashlength}{2.2pt}\setlength{\dashdash}{1.1pt} \dbox{\phantom{#1}}}

\newcommand\colorph[1][H]{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0.3pt}\setlength{\dashlength}{2.2pt}\setlength{\dashdash}{1.1pt} \colorbox{lightgray!40!Lavender!40!}{\phantom{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\[ \sqrt{\dashedph} \enspace \sqrt{\colorph}\]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for not taking a sledgehammer to crack a nut, but staying flexible.

Answer (score 8):

A simple approach (not long tested) is to use tikz. You can adjust the vertical space to your needs by replacing `A` in `\vphantom`.

[image: tikz box]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\def\dottedbox{\tikz\node[draw=black,dotted] {\vphantom{A}};}


\begin{document}
\dottedbox
$\sqrt{\dottedbox}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. If in doubt, use TikZ.